# Codeigniter - issues with pagination when setting limit and offset

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a really hard time writing this query and getting it to work right with pagination. The query itself is working perfectly. The problem is with `$query_count`, which is being passed to the controller to handle pagination.

`$query_count` should equal the total number of rows returned by the query, but right now it is being limited to 10 because I am setting a limit when I`get()`. How can I pass the limit and offset to the query, but still get the total row count from `$query`?

```
// Build query result for active projects
    if ( !empty($campus) && $campus != 'all-campuses' ) {
        $this->db->where('campus', $campus);
    }
    if ( !empty($type) && $type != 'all-types' ) {
        $this->db->where('type', $type);
    }
    if ( !empty($talent) && $talent != 'all-talent' ) {
        $this->db->like('talent', $talent);
    }
    if ( !empty($keyword) ) {
        $this->db->like('title', $keyword);
    }
    $this->db->where('active', true);
    $this->db->order_by("date_created", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get('projects', 10, $data['offset']);
    $the_rows = $query->result_array();
    $query_count = $query->num_rows();
    $query_meta['count'] =  $query_count;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write another query for getting number of rows (without limit).
It should fix your problem.

Comment: Ok... I just figured there might be a simpler / cleaner way?